# MySQL inner join on differently named columns

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to make a friends list functionality on a website i'm creating purely for my own education into learning PHP. I have a table called `friends` and it has the column names `id1`, `id2`, `status1`, `status2` - the ID of the person who has added a friend is in the `id1` column, whilst the ID of the person who was added is in the `id2` column. As for the `status1`, this holds a value 0 or 1 - it is set to 1 by default, when a friend is added - for `status2`, this is set to 0 by default and gets set to `1` when a the person who was added confirms the friends request.

Now, what i need to do is join two tables so i can ascertain the usernames of the person who was added and the person who made the request. The `id1` and `id2` relate to the `id` column in another table called `user_info`.

Now i believe i need to do an inner join on `friends` and `user_info`, however i only know how to do that when the columns share the same name. How do i do an innerjoin on two differently named columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been tested and seems to work.

With this user_info table:

[image]

And with this friends table:

[image]

Running this query:

```
select ui1.name as initiator, ui2.name as responder
from pl2.friends f
left join pl2.user_info ui1 on f.id1 = ui1.id
left join pl2.user_info ui2 on f.id2 = ui2.id
```

You get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe kinda off-topic but I want to answer your question with suggesting an other schema.

Check this out; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dde0/4

```
create table users (
  id int,
  name varchar(255)
);

create table friendships (
  user1 int,
  user2 int
);

create table friend_requests (
  user1 int,
  user2 int
);

# We have 3 users
insert into users values(1, 'John'), (2, 'Alice'), (3, 'Tom');

# John and Alice are friends
insert into friendships values(1, 2);

# Alice and Tom are friends
insert into friendships values(2, 3);

# John send Tom a friend request
insert into friend_requests values(1, 3);
```

---

```
# John's friends
select id, name from users
inner join friendships
on user2 = id and user1 = 1
or user1 = id and user2 = 1;

# Tom's friend requests
select id, name from users
inner join friend_requests on id = user1
where user2 = 3;

# Alice's friends
select id, name from users
inner join friendships
on user2 = id and user1 = 2
or user1 = id and user2 = 2;
```

Comment: Although i didn't accept this answer, i VERY much appreciate your input and will probably implement this schema when i'm refactoring.